# Clear a variable on parallel kernels

Tags: parallelization, memory

I am running the following code:

```
SetSharedVariable[a];
a= {};
x = 1;
ParallelDo[
 x += i;
 AppendTo[a, x]
 , {i, 1, 3}]
```

I want to define variable x outside the parallel computation, and then send this variable inside each kernel and perform different computations. In the end, the answer should be  a={2, 3, 4}. However, if I run this code several times, I get a={3, 5, 7},a={4, 7, 10}  and so on, because x is not cleaned inside the kernel after computation. Is there a way to clean the variable x inside each kernel, without quitting it? I tried

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ParallelEvaluate[Clear[x]];
```

without any success.

Comment: Sounds like the proper way is to write a function and pass `x` as a function argument.

Comment: You can do something like `With[{val = x}, ParallelEvaluate[x = val]]`, but it feels like a hack to me. It sounds like you are trying to treat `x` as a local variable without actually making it local.

Comment: You could just set `x=1,` immediatly after `AppendTo[a, x];` within the ParallelDo loop. But for this specific code why not just `ParallelTable[1 + i, {i, 3}]`?